# jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: ... (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, python, apache, apache-tika

Good day, everybody!

I`am trying to use Apache tika with Python and get this error:

```
jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: ä (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Could you give me a hand? I use Windows 10(x64), I guess the issue is related to encoding between python and Java or something like this. Thank you in advance.

The code I am using is:

```
import os
os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = "tika/tika-app-1.16.jar"
from jnius import autoclass

Tika = autoclass('org.apache.tika.Tika')
Metadata = autoclass('org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata')
FileInputStream = autoclass('java.io.FileInputStream')

tika = Tika()
meta = Metadata()
file_path = FileInputStream("./content/2.xlsx")
text = tika.parseToString(file_path, meta)
print(text)
```

Comment: Try specifying an absolute windows path instead of a unix-like relative path?

Comment: I have tried, nothing:(

Answer (score 1):

I know it’s late, but I had run into the exact same problem. 
It is caused by a unicode string not converting properly from Python to Java, and can be worked around by creating a Java `String` object:

```
import os
os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = "tika/tika-app-1.16.jar"
from jnius import autoclass

Tika = autoclass('org.apache.tika.Tika')
Metadata = autoclass('org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata')
FileInputStream = autoclass('java.io.FileInputStream')
String = jnius.autoclass("java.lang.String")

tika = Tika()
meta = Metadata()
file_path = FileInputStream(String("./content/2.xlsx"))
text = tika.parseToString(file_path, meta)
print(text)
```